# Power Query how to make a Table with multiple values a parameter that uses OR

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a question regarding Power Query and Tables as parameters for excel.

Right now I can create a table and use it as a parameter for Power query via Drill down.

But I'm unsure how i would proceed with a Table that has multiple values. How can a table be recognized with multiple "values" as a parameter

**For example:**

*I have the following rawdata and parameter tables*

[Rawdata+parametertables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgZLx.png)

*Now if I wanted to filter after Value2 with a parameter tables I would do a drill down of the parameter tables and load them to excel.*

*After that I have two tables that I can filter Value2 with an OR Function by 1 and 2*

Is it possible to somehow combine this into 1 Table and that it still uses an OR Function to search
Value2

Im asking because I want it to be potentially possible to just add more and more parameters into the table without creating a new table everytime. Basically just copy paste some parameters into the parameter table and be done with it

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you use Parameters only for filtering. There are other ways, but this one looks the best from performance point of view.

1. You may create Parameters table, so you have such tables:

[image]

Note, it's handy to have the same names (Value2) for key column in both tables, otherwise Table.Join will create additional column(s) after merging tables.

2. Add similar step to filter RawData table:

   join = Table.Join(RawData, "Value2", Parameters, "Value2")

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Im currently only using it for filtering. I knew about joins but I didnt even think of the idea. Is there somewhere I can readup on other methods for the future?

Comment: Not sure about the methods, but Ben Gribaudo gives a good dive into the M language: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/11/17/4107/power-query-m-primer-part1-introduction-simple-expressions-let